mDNSResponder: incoming connection from external IP address
My Little Snitch just told me that mDNSResponder tried to accept an incoming connection from an external IP (50.118.162.211). I blocked the request.
I understand that mDNSResponder is part of Bonjour, ie for discovery of devices on my local network. So I’m confused as to why I would see an external IP.
A whois check for that IP returns a company called EGIHosting and another called Detect Network Inc in San Jose, CA – a company ostensibly involved in Covid testing.
Should I be worried? Virus, spyware…

Hard to say. mDNSResponder handles regular DNS as well as mDNS/Bonjour, so it's normal for it to be talking to external DNS servers. But incoming connections are not normal. Do you know if it was over TCP or UDP, and whether you're behind network address translation (i.e. whether your computer has a 192.168.x.x, 10.x.x.x, or 172.16-31.x.x address)? Anyway, without other indications of trouble, I wouldn't worry too much about this.
